# how can i make a padding keeps outside of my div

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, sass

I'm not sure how i gonna ask this, but here it goes, i'm training css and i'm literally copying some random layout, and i find this website where he's using a padding outside the div (pic1, pic2), this way his content keeps centralized, what i want to know is how can i do this, my way (pic3, pic4) as you can see the padding keeps inside the div (which holds my section producs) making the section not centralized.

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo1dG.png)

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42dww.png)

[pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1gMV.png)

[pic4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY55Z.png)

tsx

```
      <div className={styles.sectionHeader}>
        <h1>Top Picks</h1>
        <a href="/">Ver todos</a>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.sectionWithTopPicks}>
        <div className={styles.eachItemSection}>
          <Image src={img1} width={800} height={800} layout="responsive" />
          <p>texto do produto</p>
          <h5>R$ 50,00</h5>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.eachItemSection}>
          <Image src={img1} width={800} height={800} layout="responsive" />
          <p>texto do produto</p>
          <h5>R$ 50,00</h5>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.eachItemSection}>
          <Image src={img1} width={800} height={800} layout="responsive" />
          <p>texto do produto</p>
          <h5>R$ 50,00</h5>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.eachItemSection}>
          <Image src={img1} width={800} height={800} layout="responsive" />
          <p>texto do produto</p>
          <h5>R$ 50,00</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

scss

```
.productBox {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  background: saddlebrown;
  padding: 0 40px 0 40px;

  h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }
}

.sectionHeader {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  a {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font: sans-serif;
  }
}

.eachItemSection{
  width:25%;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 0 0 0 22px;


  img{
    align-self: center;
    width: 

  }
}

.sectionWithTopPicks{
  padding-top: 50px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;

  
  p {
    color: white
  }
  h5 {
    color: white
  }
}
```

Comment: Padding is the space inside the 4 **interior** boundaries of an element. The space outside the boundaries is the ***margin***.

Comment: a guy on discord helped me with margin-left:  -22x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your objective, but you have to adjust the code.

With the flexbox approach, you can:

1. Use a flex-div to hold your items with: `.sectionWithTopPick { display: flex; }`
2. Inside it, use a div to hold the content, and tell the div how to fit the parent flex-box with `flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 25%` (this tells to the inside div to never grow beyond 25%, but to shrink if necessary). This div also has the padding.
3. Select the first item with **:fisrt-child** and remove **left-padding**
4. Select the last item with **:last-child** and remove **right-padding**
5. Use another div to contain the item's contents, and make it's image fill 100% of the space.

[Here a codepen with working solution](https://codepen.io/aledebarba/pen/poRNQXw)

Answer (score 0):

How you can see here the **CSS box-model** explain that `padding` and `border` are part of the html element.

[image]

You can also play [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp). So you can use margin if you want a space outside the div.

For align i can advise to use `margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ale Macedo's answer but I'd make the following changes.

```
.eachItemSection {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 2vh .5vw;
      &:first-child {
    padding-left: 1vw;
  }   &:last-child {
    padding-right: 1vw;
  }
```